# Can an adverb be a predicate?

Tags: grammar

Consider the following quote,

[image]

> “Life is once. Forever.” —Henri Cartier-Bresson, AZ Quotes

I have checked that "once" is an adverb. How can it become a predicate?

Comment: To me, this is an unidiomatic use, probably used deliberately, to make a point.

Comment: It could be a translation from the French, I don't know enough French to guess what the original might be. However 'Forever' on its own isn't a sentence either. What Cartier-Bresson seems to have been saying (whether in French or English) is that anything which happens in any split second  (and can be photographed using a 35mm Leica) is unique and will never be repeated in exactly the same way so each candid photograph is unique. He was using language for effect and is allowed poetic licence as far as I'm concerned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adverbs could be part of a predicate, to be more exact, a *subjective complement*, but it doesn't happen very often and they are used either idiomatically or in a sentence where a participle or part of the sentence is elided.

In your quote, "Life is once" could be considered as short for

> Life is **given** to people once. Life is **lived** once by
>   people.

and it doesn't necessarily mean *once* is a subjective complement alone once elided words are placed. The past participle *given* or *lived* is elided in your example.

> He will be (coming) back in 5 minutes: coming is elided.
>
> He is out (of the house/building/restaurant...): a place is elided.
>
> The secret is out: the secret has been discovered/revealed/known.

There are more examples where an adverb could be used as a subjective complement. They should be learned on a case-by-case basis.

Comment: Ah, apart from that the fact that *back* and *out* are considered prepositions in many modern grammars precisely  because they can function as Predicative Complements, whereas *adverbs* can't (apart from when *BE* is used in its specifying sense: *How I want you to dance is beautifully*, for example).

Comment: @Araucaria *How I want you to dance is ((to) dance) beautifully*. It is not an adverb acting as a predicative complement. To infinitive or bare-infinitive is elided.

Comment: Well, that's how it's analysed by Aarts, H&P, Quirk et al and so on. But if you're correct, then that's even stronger evidence that adverbs don't occur as Complements of the verb *BE*! ;-)

Comment: @Araucaria Yes, that's why I said it is an idiomatic expressions. The game is **over**. It could be an adverb, adjective or even **preposition** depending on your way of perceiving this sentence. I always agree with you, remember?

Comment: You often make insightful and interesting  points. I don't want you to always agree with me because I'll never learn anything! :-)

Answer (score 3):

Some adverbs definitely can be predicates: words of location - *here, indoors, abroad* - are usually seen as adverbs, and obviously commonly used as predicates.

One could make the case that the common construction *{event<sub>noun</sub>}{be}{time<sub>adverb</sub>}* (e.g. "the concert was yesterday") also uses adverbs as predicates.
But another view would be that the *{be}* there is used not as a copula but in the meaning "to happen, take place", in which case it's not using the adverb as a predicate.
Both those views are reasonable, though I'd lean towards the latter.

"Life is once" seems to follow that pattern, so whether *once* is a predicate in that particular phrase depends on how you choose to analyse the *is*.

Either way, it's certainly not a common kind of usage of *once*. I'd go so far as to suggest it was intentionally chosen to grab attention with how unusual it is.

---

(Terminology note: For sentences like "Jill is tall", I've seen the word *predicate* sometimes referring just to the "tall" and other times to the whole "is tall". In this answer I'm using the word the same way the OP did.)

Answer (score 2):

It is not grammatical but it is understandable metaphorical language.  It is an advertising slogan where, as with poetry, certain liberties can be taken.

The problem is that **Life** and **is** and **once** do not go together except metaphorically.

**Life** is an abstraction.  That is, not "*a* life" (a particular life) but the concept that refers to a state of animation, of being alive.

We can use the verb **is** with abstract concepts, for **is** means not only **exists** but **can be said to be**.

Life is short -> Life can be said to be short. "X is {predicate complement}" means that X *has the qualities* which {predicate complement} refers to.

**once** modifies things which **occur**.  We normally say "That *happened* once".

When we complete the verb **is** with the adverbial complement **once**, we treat the verb **is** as if it were synonymous with the verb **happens**, which it is not.

By extension, when we treat the verb **is** as if it means "happens", we treat the subject of the predicate, **Life**, as if it were not an abstraction but an event:   *Life happens...*  but abstractions or concepts cannot "happen".

The predicate subject complement *recasts* the predicate and the subject into meanings they do not have except metaphorically, by recasting them from their actual grammatical categories into other grammatical categories.  The statement violates the rules of grammar but in an intelligible manner.

Here's what happens if we include "Forever" :)

```
    while(true)
      {
         for i = 1 to 1 {
           var result = (Event)Life
         }
      }
```

Comment: How about "The life is once."?

Comment: "The life" refers to a particular life.  But a life does not "occur" as **once** implies that it does.  We are still in the realm of the metaphorical. The grammatical categories are still being disrupted.  A grammatical version would be "We live only once." or "We are alive only once".

Comment: Here is a famous poem where similar recasting of grammatical categories occurs; https://www.poets.org/poetsorg/poem/anyone-lived-pretty-how-town

Answer (score 2):

Confusion may arise from taking lexical categories too seriously.  In the first place the verb *to be* has a long history of meaning to occur or to happen.  The *OED*'s earliest cite is from 950 CE, and continues to such modern usage as

> The flower show **was** last week.

*Once* may be used as an adjective or as a noun (in the *OED*'s parlance, as a *quasi-adj*[ective] and *quasi-sb* [substantive, i.e, noun], respectively).  As a noun, meaning "doing a thing once, going once, etc." the *OED* cites a 1623 source

> **Once** is no Custome

and notes the modern usage

> **Once** a week is enough for me.

"Life is once" is an unusual phrasing -- "You have but one life" would be more common -- but its easily-recognized meaning flows from long-standing usage.

Answer (score 1):

Any sentence consists of the two parts known as (1) the subject, and (2) the predicate.

The word predicate has several homonyms of itself. -Grammatically, the noun which is the word "predicate" means that very part of a sentence apart from the subject, which is usually - in fact - most of the sentence, or the rest of the sentence, really.

So, in this sentence, "X is once," then "is once" is the predicate, and the word "once" is part of the predicate. That is all, here.

As to the alleged quote in the picture which is shown as part of the original post here, it is NOT a quotation but is rather an unsubstantiated allegation! -One must ALWAYS cite the source properly & reliably. -Similarly, for photographs - especially in this day and age of Photoshop & the internet - ALWAYS cite a photograph's provenance; -Sticking a photograph next to an alleged quotation with a person's name there simply does not prove a thing! For example, are we to assume that the photograph is that person who has been named? -Or we're supposed to know already, somehow, that the photograph is that person? Even if the photograph were a true image of that person, it doesn't prove that the person in question even ever said such a thing as the alleged quotation!

ALWAYS cite the source properly and reliably. "Az Quotes" and its ilk are NOT reliable sources and do not constitute citation since they do not even practise proper citation themselves. Their only practice is click-baiting.

Answer (score 0):

***is once*** is the predicate.

It's a silly quote.

Comment: It is grammatically correct? Or just its meaning sounds silly?

Comment: @YasashiiEirian: It is grammatically correct. "Silly" in this case is a euphemism for "a piece of shit." As in, "It's a piece of shit quote."

Comment: @YasashiiEirian: I take that back: It is not _totally_ grammatically correct. It's soft of okay. Kind of. Correct with an asterisk. Colloquial-ish. And silly.